# How class can be a data type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am having a problem to understand the codes below.

```
export class Movie {
    id:number;
    movieName:string;
    genre:string;
}
```

Now one data type or maybe a list of objects was created from `Movie` class. Here is the code:

```
    import { Movie } from "./movie";

    export var FakeMovies : Movie[] = [
    {
        id : 1,
        movieName : "Avatar",
        genre : "Action/ SiFi"
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        movieName : "3 Idiots",
        genre : "Funny"
    }
]
```

My question is, if it is set of objects, then why is `Movie[]` is used? Isn't an array while as `Movie` is a class? Can somebody please explain this code? What changes should make in `fakeMovies` if there is a constructor on `Movie` class?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html. Movie: the type of one Movie. Movie[]: the type of an array of Movie objects. Equivalent to Array<Movie>. What exactly is unclear?

Comment: i see. i think i got it now. can u please tell me what will happen if there is a constructor on Movie class, and you have to initialize while u want to create an object from it, then how would u create list of object from it ? @JBNizet

Comment: `const fakeMoview: Movie[] = [new Movie(...), new Movie(...)];`.

Answer (score 1):

In the example provided, `Movie` is a class with three fields: (1) `id` of type `number`, (2) `movieName` of type `string`, and (3) `genre` of type `string`. By default, fields without a visibility modifier are `public` (see the official [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-by-default)). In Typescript, just as with JavaScript, an object can be created using JavaScript Object Notation (JSON), providing a value for each of the fields. Thus, the snippet for `FakeMovies` is an array of `Movie` objects (two of them), each with a value provided for the fields using JSON (which maps the name/key of the field to its respective value).

If you had a constructor for the `Movie` class, such as the following

```
export class Movie {
    id:number;
    movieName:string;
    genre:string;

    constructor(id: number, movieName: string, genre: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.movieName = movieName;
        this.genre = genre;
    }
}
```

you could create the array as follows:

```
export var FakeMovies : Movie[] = [
    new Movie(1, "Avatar", "Action/ SiFi"),
    new Movie(2, "3 Idiots", "Funny")
];
```

Note that you can also shorten the constructor definition by making the fields of `Movie` `private`, as is the convention of Typescript (see [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))). This would reduce the `Movie` class to the following:

```
export class Movie {
    constructor(private id: number, private movieName: string, private genre: string) {}
}
```

Comment: Making the fields private doesn't make much sense here. They should stay public. But you can shorten the code the same way by using public instead of private.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript uses structural compatibility to determine compatibility between types. In your example the `Movie` class has just 3 public properties, so **ANY** object with those 3 properties will be compatible with the `Movie` class, but that does not mean they are actually instances of the `Movie` class. In your case `FakeMovies[0] insrtanceof Movie` will be false.

If you want to actually create instances of the movie class you can define a constructor and use it to create objects of the class :
    export class Movie {
        constructor(public id: number, public movieName: string, public genre: string) {}
    }

```
export var FakeMovies : Movie[] = [
    new Movie(1, "Avatar", "Action/ SiFi"),
    new Movie(2, "3 Idiots", "Funny")
];
```

You could also just new up the object and set the fields independently  (`let m = new Movie(); m.id = 10; ...`)

If you want to make sure that people are not assigning object literals that have the same shape as `Movie` but are not actually instances of `Movie`, you can create a private fields that will render any object literal incompatible with the `Movie` class

```
export class Movie {
    private nonStructural!:true;
    constructor(public  id: number, public  movieName: string, public  genre: string) {}
}
// will now be an error
export var FakeMovies2 : Movie[] = [
    {
        id : 1,
        movieName : "Avatar",
        genre : "Action/ SiFi"
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        movieName : "3 Idiots",
        genre : "Funny"
    }
]
```